# MatOfPoint to MatOfPoint2f Size Opencv java

Tags: java, opencv

I'm working on Java OpenCV project and I want to find the mayor and minor axis of a shape. Im usng fitEllipse method, but Eclipse throws the following error:

OpenCV Error: Incorrect size of input array (Number of points should be >= 5) in cvFitEllipse2, file ........\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\shapedescr.cpp, line 799

The size later conversion is 1x1. Why this happen?

```
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();    
Imgproc.findContours(sourceImg, contours, new Mat(),Imgproc.RETR_LIST,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

for(int i=0; i< contours.size();i++){
//Conversion between MatOfPoint to MatOfPoint2f
MatOfPoint2f temp=new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(i).toArray());      
RotatedRect elipse1=Imgproc.fitEllipse(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### On the code level

You need `temp` to have at least 5 points in it in order to call `Imgproc.fitEllipse(temp)`.

check out [opencv's source here](http://ehc.ac/p/emgucv/opencv/ci/ce2edd137d0799e1a836176379150ab464552c4c/tree/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp#l972).
You'll see that the `cvFitEllipse2` (which is used by `fitEllipse`) checks for a minimal number of 5 points.

#### On the mathematical level

I'm not entirely sure why you **must** have at least 5 points mathematically to do this, but as I read [here](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=486081), 4 points does not fully lock the ellipse.

Also, if you're into the mathematics of it, check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632442/calculate-ellipse-from-points) one out too (It also has inner links to other explanations).

Comment: Thanks Arnon! But the problem is than before conversion (MatOfPoints) the number of points are more than 5. Later, the size of the MatOfPoints2f become 1x1. I think that the problem is in the conversion between these two. The method fitEllipse only accept MatOfPoint2f in parameters.

Answer (score 3):

yes,The method fitEllipse only accept MatOfPoint2f in parameters.So you have to convert MatOfPoint to MatOfPoint2f,you can easily do this:

`MatOfPoint2f temp=new MatOfPoint2f();
temp.fromList(contours.get(i).toList());
RotatedRect elipse1=Imgproc.fitEllipse(temp);`